# System stack allocation in recursion

Tags: java, operating-system, jvm, heap-memory

As we all know that all most all recursive functions can be modified to iterative approach. Suppose we take an example of adding two linklists which represent two huge numbers. This question can be solved either by recursion (which uses system stack) or iterative (explicit stack usage) approach.

My doubt here is if i have given jvm heap size as `-Xms2048MB -Xmx2048M` then in the recursive approach will it use all the heap memory for system stack? AFAIK if i will use explicit stack then it can consume all these memory. It will great if somebody can also tell me how, when and how much system stack memory is allocated and little bit of workings. Even pointing to some nice tutorials also will be of great help. As far as possible if it can be confined w.r.t. `java` world then it's good. Thanks.

Comment: Note: a `String` is a reference which can be on the stack, but the actual object is on the heap. If you use objects, you should assume they will use heap space no matter what you do.

Comment: BTW I would just write `-Xmx2g` or `-mx2g` or not set it all, the default is 1/4 of the main memory size and as long as you have a decent machine, you might not need to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible to occur as the stack frame has its own size. This size can be adjusted by the command line parameter `-Xss<size>`.

The heap memory is completly separated from this stack memory.

The default stack size depends on the JVM you're running

Comment: +1 The stack doesn't use any heap, but any objects referenced will still be on the heap. e.g. if you use objects via recursion or iteration they are on the heap, not the stack.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's a valid point but from how I understand the question the original poster wanted to know if the stack eats up all heap...

Comment: true, but the stack might not get eaten up the way the OP thinks and the OP could run out of heap before running out of stack, thus the confusion.

Comment: +1 @Uwe Plonus  what does this system stack contains then because if all the objects are getting allocated in heap? Any good links or book for this to understand in-depth. Thanks.

Comment: @Trying In principle only the return addresses and the pointers of the values to the call are stored on the stack. You can read more in the [VM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2).